# Filter and show only SVG images in ApostropheCMS

Tags: svg, apostrophe-cms

I created a new filter named `svg` to show only svg images or non-svg images.

But I don't understand where can I set the filter value to `true` or `false`?

The code is shown below.

Widget index file:

```js
module.exports = {
  label: 'Section SVG Images',
  addFields: [
    {
      name: 'svg-images',
      label: 'SVG Images',
      type: 'singleton',
      widgetType: 'apostrophe-images',
      filters: {
        svg: true
      },
      required: true
    },
  ]
};
```

Custom cursor filter:

```js
module.exports = {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.addFilter('svg', {
      finalize: function() {
        var svg = self.get('svg'); // <--- HARE svg is olways 'undefined' 

        if (typeof svg == 'undefined') {
          return;
        }

        if (svg) {
          var criteria = {
            'attachment.extension': 'svg'
          };
        } else {
          var criteria = {
            'attachment.extension': { $ne: 'svg' }
          };
        }

        self.and(criteria);
      },

      safeFor: 'public',
      launder: function(a) {
        return self.apos.launder.boolean(a);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` is not a top level option for `singleton` fields in Apostrophe. That is unique to `join`-type fields. You could have this widget extend `apostrophe-pieces-widgets`, then you could probably set that same `filters` object directly on the new pieces widget. That should register the cursor filter, at least.

It's worth noting that there is [currently a PR in progress](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/pull/2637) to add filtering by both file type and orientation to Apostrophe core!